# Cordova connect with Node.js Sockect.io Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, cordova, socket.io

"I'm trying to make my Cordova app talk to my Socket.io Server built with Node.js, but it's not working! I made a mobile app using Cordova and set up a real-time communication server using Node.js and Socket.io. However, when I try to connect them, it's not happening.

I need some help figuring out what's going wrong. If you have any advice on how to connect a Cordova app to a Socket.io server or if there are common mistakes I might be making, I'd really appreciate your help.

Thanks a bunch!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="app">
      <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
      <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
        <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
        <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript/Cordova**

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  try {
    const socket = io("https://chat-ten-umber.vercel.app");
    socket.on("connect", function () {
      alert("Yeeeeeeeee");
      socket.on("text", function (text) {
        alert(text);
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }
});
```

Server:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const cors = require("cors");
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.use(cors());

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("A user is connected");

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("The user disconnect");
  });

  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    console.log("Received message:", data);
    socket.broadcast.emit("message", { message: data.message, to: data.to });
  });
});

// start server
http.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port 8000");
});

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("Hello");
});
```